# Accessing elements of the dictionary in a loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a dataset:

```
city_names_lst = 
  [{"cities":
     {"city":
         {"name":"New York",
          "population": "18mln",
          "suburbs": 
             {"s_name": "Brooklyn",
              "population":"9mln"},
             {"s_name": "Queens",
              "population": "9mln"}}},
     {"city":
         {"name":"Washington DC",
          "population":"10mln",
         "suburbs": 
             {"s_name": "Maryland",
              "population": "5mln"},
             {"s_name": "Northern Virginia",
              "population":"5mln"}}},
      ...}]
```

I need to iterate through the entire list and access the "name" key.

The code I have is:

```
city_names = []

for x in city_names_list:
    city_names = x['city']['name']
```

However, it only fetches the first city name. 
How do I get all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close.  *Append* to the list, rather than reassigning its name:

```
city_names = []

for x in city_names_list:
    city_names.append(x['city']['name'])
```

I'm assuming your data is not really all nested behind a "cities" key, like it is in the example dataset.

Comment: thanks, the nested dictionaries is actually more complex - I adjusted the code in the example.